# something about how to draw the topological diagram dynamically in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, topology

I've never done this before. I don't know which control or what class I can use to solve it, can you give me some advice? I am using C#, and my platform is visual studio 2010.

Comment: You should state more clearly what you want and what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago for 2D CAD like program I used [piccolo2d](http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/) with a great success. It's a good writtent 2D library, completely written in `C#`. We should by the way a customize it a little bit for our own needs in order to run it faster in our specific contest, but I repeat I got a very good feeling form it.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for your answer，I just use GDI+ draw the icon and the line between，and put this code in timer control ，and set the interval